How to add another background area under my svg?
I have a home page that currently has a decent layout, it's all put together okay, but if I want to add more content, then the page will go down below the height of the svg on the home screen. I want to add more content so all I need is a white background to flow underneath to "carry on" from the svg as its a white wave pattern, so will look like it just continues. I am not sure how to do this. What I try either makes it appear at the top of the screen or just has a transparent gap underneath the svg where the content is, obviously I want this background to be behind the content.
Here is what I have right now, Its working fine but only because the content on the page doesn't go below the height of the svg, if it does then it just creates transparent space so I can see the rest of the gradient background which isn't what I want.
Where the SVG is used:
import React from "react";

const WhiteSection: React.FC = () => {
  return (
      <div className="relative w-full">
        <svg
          id="visual"
          viewBox="0 0 900 600"
          width="900"
          height="600"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          version="1.1"
          className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-auto z-10"
        >
          <path
            d="M0 333L21.5 326.7C43 320.3 86 307.7 128.8 320.7C171.7 333.7 214.3 372.3 257.2 376.3C300 380.3 343 349.7 385.8 318.2C428.7 286.7 471.3 254.3 514.2 257C557 259.7 600 297.3 642.8 313C685.7 328.7 728.3 322.3 771.2 308.8C814 295.3 857 274.7 878.5 264.3L900 254L900 601L878.5 601C857 601 814 601 771.2 601C728.3 601 685.7 601 642.8 601C600 601 557 601 514.2 601C471.3 601 428.7 601 385.8 601C343 601 300 601 257.2 601C214.3 601 171.7 601 128.8 601C86 601 43 601 21.5 601L0 601Z"
            fill="#eeeeee"
          ></path>
          <path
            d="M0 492L21.5 494C43 496 86 500 128.8 484.8C171.7 469.7 214.3 435.3 257.2 415.7C300 396 343 391 385.8 395.5C428.7 400 471.3 414 514.2 430.7C557 447.3 600 466.7 642.8 463.5C685.7 460.3 728.3 434.7 771.2 421.8C814 409 857 409 878.5 409L900 409L900 601L878.5 601C857 601 814 601 771.2 601C728.3 601 685.7 601 642.8 601C600 601 557 601 514.2 601C471.3 601 428.7 601 385.8 601C343 601 300 601 257.2 601C214.3 601 171.7 601 128.8 601C86 601 43 601 21.5 601L0 601Z"
            fill="#ffffff"
          ></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
  );
};

export default WhiteSection;

How it's used in the layout of the page:
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Loading from '../../components/Loading';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import GradientBackground from './GradientBackground';
import WhiteSection from './WhiteSection';

const LandingLayout = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <div className="relative overflow-hidden">
        <GradientBackground />
        <WhiteSection />
        <div className="relative z-30">
          <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 z-50">
            <Navbar />
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen mt-16">
            {children}
          </div>
          <div className="mt-auto z-40">
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default LandingLayout;

